# Why is this script saying Echo is off?

Tags: windows, batch-file

this code is supposed to set the contents of a file as a variable, but is not working. Note that I have `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of the script.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('out.txt') do set duh=!duh! %ii
echo %duh% > Displaynames\Name.txt
```

and

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('out.txt') do set duh=%duh% %ii
echo %duh% > Displaynames\Name.txt
```

do not work. `Displaynames\Name.txt` reads `ECHO is off.`

Any idea what Im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: There's so much I don't understand with your question. But first off, you don't have any delimiters stated, you know that or?

Comment: `%ii` should be `%%i`.

Comment: @niCkcAMel - `"delims="` is so that the entire line gets read in at once. By default, `for /f` delimits on whitespace.

Comment: You should open up a cmd prompt and at least read the first dozen lines of the help for the FOR command.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Im not sure what the problem was but for others I found that this script worked instead:

```
set cmd="type out.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %cmd% ') DO SET X=%%i
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%x%") do set x=%%a
for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do if "!x:~-1!"==" " set 
x=!x:~0,-1!
echo %x% > Displaynames\Name.txt
```

Thanks for all who helped, sorry I could not share the whole script.
EDIT: I changed this so that it removes the extra space.

Comment: This code, outputs the last line of `out.txt` plus a space, _(as long as it doesn't contain problematic characters)_, to `Displaynames\Name.txt`. Asking or searching for, "how do I write the last line of a file to another file" wasn't too difficult a proposition, and would never have meant revealing your soon to be copyrighted code!

Comment: Yes I found that too but that script did not work, hence my using this one. I am also aware of the extra space but it is something I need.

Answer (score 1):

The message is because `%duh%` isn't defined, i.e. it hasn't been set to anything. *The reason being that you have used single quotes inside your parentheses*.

Does this give you what you need:

```bat
Set "duh="
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("out.txt") Do Set "duh=!duh! %%A"
>"Displaynames\Name.txt" Echo %duh:~1%
```

**Edit**

Upon reflection, it occurs to me that your `out.txt` file may only contain a single line, *and possibly only a single word, e.g.`Jen`*.

If that is the case, then something like this, which set's the first line of a file to a variable, would be a great improvement:

```bat
Set/P "duh="<"out.txt"
>"Displaynames\Name.txt" Echo %duh%
```

Comment: that did not work for me, it echoed "ii ii" into the text file. the contents of Out.txt was Jen.

Comment: I have added a line to my answer specifically removing any defined `%duh%` variable first, _(because the only way a string which wasn't in `out.txt` could be written was if you had already set it beforehand)_. My script should write each line of `out.txt` space separated as a single line to `Displaynames\Name.txt`. If that isn't what you wanted to do, try re-evaluating your question!

Comment: @MarkDodsons Before telling "didn't work", test given answers. If you are getting `ii ii` is because you still using your wrong code with `%ii` instead of testing this anwer.

Comment: Im hesitant to share the entire code with you as I plan on copyrighting the code later... However I think there is something in the code interfering with this current section.

Comment: @Mark, I didn't ask about the rest of your code but there is nothing which could interfere with mine. There may be possible problems in your code; such as `out.txt` is empty, isn't relative to the current directory, is unicode or doesn't use CRLF line endings and `Displaynames` not being a directory relative to current; but none of those can be my fault. Since you posted your answer, added to what has gone before, I realised that you may be trying to do something completely different, therefore I have made an **Edit** to my answer with an alternative, I hope it better reflects your intention.

Comment: @Compo Out.txt has one line of text always, and It is relative. See the script below. your edited final answer also did not work for me, I had tried that.

Comment: @Compo Well I can guarantee that that did not work. Time and time again I am frustrated by people who come to the conclusion that I am wrong instead of thinking that perhaps something exists that they do not know about. **I Tried your code and it did not work**! it simply outputted random gibberish like `ii` and `>` and `A.A` I find that your responses are much ruder than mine. Batch files give no error messages and I can tell you **FOR CERTAIN** that your script **DID NOT WORK** no matter what I did. & Don't worry Compo, this will be my last post on Stack Overflow as I am done with this site.

Comment: I did not mean to be rude or offensive and I am grateful that you attempted to help. However, you were unable to help and instead of accepting that you basically just called me an idiot and told me that I was wrong, and that your code does work in my script, even though **You are not the one who wrote the code, and you are not the one who is testing it!**

Comment: No Mark, as well as being relative, _which you answered_, I also explained that If your `out.txt` file is unicode or doesn't use CRLF line endings there may be issues, _which you did not confirm_. I will reiterate, if those things are untrue, it is not possible for my answers to not work and your less efficient answer to do so, unless you have not used them exactly as I wrote them! Post exactly what you have added to your script, from my answer(s) and properly explain how it fails to work _(as was mentioned to you also by @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ two days ago)_.

Comment: @Compo The only difference from your code it's instead of DisplayNames\Name.txt I have DisplayNames\%1         the contents of out.txt was just one word: "Jen" with no spaces or characters. The script outputted "%a-is off" sorry I don't have code set to code I'm on moble.

Comment: When you have the information, please return and post it here, _if needs be as an edit to your post such that the format etc cannot be mistaken_.

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax. It's  `for /f .... in ('command') do ...`
You try to *execute* `out.txt` (which doesn't give you any feedback), so you get nothing back.
To verify, try:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo hello') do echo %%a
```

What you (probably) want, is getting the *content* of the file. Syntax for that is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do echo %%a
```

As filenames could contain spaces, it's better to quote it:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do echo %%a
```

Note: In some other languages you can both use single quoting `'` or double quoting `"`. In batch, there is only double quoting `"`. The single quoting here is a special thing of `for`, to tell it, that it should execute, what's inside.